# Detect if mouse is touching element using Prototype.js?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I am attempting to make an Javascript application where an element will slowly fade out when the mouse is touching it and fade in when the mouse is off the element. I'm using Prototype with Scriptaculous, so is there a Prototype function that can tell me whether or not the mouse is touching an object at any given time?

My main problem using Scriptaculous FadeOut/FadeIn effects is that when one is triggered before the other has finished, the effects conflict and the element misbehaves.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the effect object somewhere (for instance in a closure), and cancel it when you want to apply a different effect

```
var element = $("element"),
    currentEffect = null;

element.observe("mouseenter", function() {
    if (currentEffect) {
        currentEffect.cancel();
    }
    currentEffect = new Effect.Fade(element);
});

element.observe("mouseleave", function() {
    if (currentEffect) {
        currentEffect.cancel();
    }
    currentEffect = new Effect.Appear(element);
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cxw3q/2/)

(obviously you can refactor that in several ways, but basically all you need to do is observer the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, and remember to cancel any running effect before starting a new one)

Comment: in Opera, if you keep hovering until it is 100% gone, when you mouseleave, it becomes visible without any fade in effect.

Comment: @ajax333221 Must be an Opera-specific bug. Not seeing it Chrome, Safari, or Firefox. I don't have Opera handy, and frankly I can't be bothered to debug it. And the code's still valid, browser issues notwithstanding. Thanks for the heads-up though

Comment: Perhaps the Opera bug happens because you are cancelling an effect after it has completed? You could add an `afterFinish` [callback](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/core-effects/) to clear the `currentEffect` variable and so avoid that behaviour.